# Use a variable as a name for a directory

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a script in python that creates a folder entitled the current timestamp, but don't really know the syntax to do it. So far I have this:

```
timestamp = int(time.time()) #fetches timestamp
if not os.path.exists([timestamp]): #creates new folder titled the current timestamp
    os.makedirs([timestamp])
os.chdir([timestamp]) #navigates to new folder
```

When I run this, I run into errors.

P.S. I am a beginner, please don't bite.

Comment: And what is the problem? Did you get any errors?

Answer (score 2):

The timestamp needs to be converted to a `str`ing. and then that `str`ing need to be passed as the argument to the `os` functions:

```
timestamp = str(int(time.time())) #fetches timestamp
if not os.path.exists(timestamp): #creates new folder titled the current timestamp
    os.makedirs(timestamp)
os.chdir(timestamp) #navigates to new folder
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot!